# Rails: How to set a background image in rails from css?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, background-image

I am using rails 3.2 and i have to set a background for one of the page and i have tried many ways and nothing went right, so looking for some good help. I have tried

```
background: url(<%= asset_path 'background.jpg' %>)

background: url("public/background.jpg");

background-image:url('/assets/images/background.jpg')
```

and nothing worked. Please help me.

Comment: surprised no one has taken time to up-vote this considering it has been viewed 2236 times. 1+ form me.

Comment: `background: url(<%= asset_path 'background.jpg' %>)` worked for me http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In your CSS:

```
background-image: url(background.jpg);
```

or

```
background-image: url(/assets/background.jpg);
```

In `environments/production.rb`:

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)  
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS  
config.assets.compress = true

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed  
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs  
config.assets.digest = true
```

Comment: where you add your css files?

Comment: it is in assets/stylesheets/application.css

Comment: Do i have to set any thing in application.rb or in environments file?

Comment: If your images are in public images folder? please put it in assets images folder

Comment: In your layout `<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application.css" %>`

Comment: No i have my images in the app/assets/images directory.

Comment: see my post try this background-image: url(/assets/background.jpg) let me know

Comment: Still not working. All the other functionality like text color etc works but not the image.

Comment: in which environment you are running? production?

Comment: check these `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` `config.assets.enabled = true` ?

Comment: development environment.

Comment: check your application.rb `config.assets.enabled = true`

Comment: can you tell me what it is showing when you do http://localhost:3000/background.jpg hope you are running your server in 3000 port

Comment: Ok...then it is your css problem have you checked you did not miss semicolon in css and css validator to valid your css like `background-image: url(background.jpg);` OR `background-image: url(/assets/background.jpg);`

Comment: How can I set this only to a specific page. For example, I want to display a `background-image` only for the login page?

Comment: Adding the !important flag was all it took to get mine working.

Comment: Convert css to scss may help and use @import in application.scss

Other than this, change url to asset-url, font-url 
Except these nothing needs to change.

Answer (score 30):

For sass (scss) this code works with the following image path

**app/assets/images/pictureTitle.png**

```
body { 
  background-image: image-url('pictureTitle.png'); 
}
```

You might also need to restart your rails server.

Answer (score 12):

If you have the image in your public directory like public/bg.jpg

```
background-image: url('/bg.jpg')
```

If you have image in app/assets/images/bg.jpg

```
 background-image: url('/assets/bg.jpg')
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. What in case i have my  image in app/assets/images?

Answer (score 5):

Lots of answers for this one, figured I'd throw in my solution, which addresses the original question, since they were originally attempting to use, among other things, an ERB helper:

following the [link from above from Kangkyu](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb), I learned it's possible to add the .erb file extension onto my .css file. Which is definitely what Kangkyu did.

application.css.erb

This gives me access to the helper methods.

Instead of fussing with figuring out the correct path to the image, I used:

```
<%= asset_path "image_name.png" %>
```

so my CSS property/value pair looks like this:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'foo.jpg' %>);
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using sass (scss), use image-url function:

```
body {
  background-image: image-url('texture.png'); // link to /assets/images/texture.png
}
```

Comment: But sir it didn't, what do you think the problem sir?

Answer (score 3):

The problem could be more deeply ingrained than you think. It most likely is not a Rails asset problem as many presume, but *'miscommunication'* between your html elements. Here's why:

1. First of all, fool proof your code by puting the backgound image in the `body` element.

   ```
   body {
   background: url('pic-name.jpg') no-repeat center center;
   background-size: cover;}  /* For a full size background image */
   ```
2. Then check your developer tools console to see if the image is getting loaded correctly or it's giving a 404 not found.
3. If giving a 404, then your css syntax is not correct, try any other of this post's answers until you no longer get a 404. For me the above example worked:
4. Once you realize that the console doesn't give a 404 anymore, confirm the image actually loads with this:

   http://localhost:3000/assets/pic-name.jpg

   - I understand that this could vary per individual, but try it and make sure you've used your pic's name.
5. If it loads well, now you know the culprit - the `body` element is hiding something - when you put the image in the `body`, it works, when you put it in another element, it works not.
6. This is the trick; in that `other` element where you want the background image, mine was `header`, insert some text or some lines, Yes, just plain text or something! Mine was:

   ```
   <header>
      <%= render 'shared/navbar' %> # To have the nav's backgrond as the image
      <div class="container">
         <div class="text-center">
           <h2><strong>Nairobi</strong></h2> <hr>
           <h2><strong>Is</strong></h2> <hr>
           <h2><strong>Just a Beula Land</strong></h2> <hr>
         </div>
     </div>
   ```
7. And alas, it worked! Though it didn't show the full image, just the upper part. But at least I knew it worked.
8. And if you add more text, the image stretches downwards (more gets shown)

Hope this helps someone.
And along with this I realised that it was not that easy to place the background image to cover the `nav` as well, esp if using bootstrap; both the `nav` and your other element need to be `children` of the same `parent element`, eg, mine was the `header` as shown above, and you'll also have to render the nav inside your, say, `homepage.html.erb`, and every other page, as opposed to just rendering it on the `application.html.erb`

**Update**

Okay, this is what I did to show the full background image without inserting texts here and there. In my `application.scss`, where you have your css, I simply added the height property, like so

```
     body {
background: url('pic-name.jpg') no-repeat center center;
background-size: cover;
height: 600px;}
```

N.B: Using `height: 100%` didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I followed the suggestions above (Thank you!) - just in case it doesn't work for others either - this solution worked for me:

```
.myClass {
   background: image-url('myPicture.png');
}
```

so instead of "background-image" I had to use "background" in my scss.

Answer (score 2):

I had this challenge when working on a rails 6 application.

**Here's how I fixed it**:

For an image located in `app/assets/images/my-image.jpg`, assuming that it is a CSS background image, you should reference this way:

```
background-image: url(<%= /assets/my-image.jpg' %>)
```

For an image located in `app/assets/images/slides/my-slide.jpg`, assuming that it is a CSS background image, you should reference this way:

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'slides/my-slide.jpg' %>)
```

**Note**: This worked well in development and production environments

You can read up more on this in the official Rails Documentation: [Coding Links to Assets](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb)

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this for an entire day. Finally I got it working in both development and production by coding the css in the view that holds the background image:

```
<head>
    <style>
        #tile {
            background: url(<%= asset_path 'background.jpg' %>);
            background-size: cover;
            }
    </style>        
</head>
```

Then on the sheet itself I created a div with id=tile like this:

```
<div id=tile>
  <div class=row>
  ...added more stuff
  </div>
</div>
```

Ruby 2.3.7 Rails 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

Ok, hope this helps someone!! I was in a similar situation recently looking to implement an image for a theme.
This solution worked for me in a home_page_header.html.erb file provided that you have an image called blog_image.jpeg in your app/assets/images folder:

```
<!-- Page Header -->
<header class='masthead' style='background-image: url(assets/blog_image.jpeg)'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto'>
        <div class='site-heading'>
          <h1>Omega</h1>
          <span class='subheading'>Sample text</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: This worked for me in development, but not production.  Still haven't figured out how to make it work in production.

Answer (score 0):

[CONTEXT] Ruby 2.6.3 | Rails 6.0.1 | Using webpack to bundle stylesheets.

I realized I couldn't deliver images from the asset pipeline in [s]css from webpack files: for instance, Asset Helpers from sass-rails are unavailable.

After some struggle, I found the solution on https://stackoverflow.com/a/57175231/8131629

Answer (score -1):

Try the code below:

```
.background-style {
    background-image: url("../images/background.jpg");
}
```

Answer (score -2):

if you have your image into app/assets/images and its name is 'zi-fullscreen-bg.png', for example
then you can use

```
.hero-unit.fullscreen-image-bg {
  background-image: url('zi-fullscreen-bg.png');
}
```

at least it worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

It seems that double quotes work.

Here is my example:

```
body {
  background-image: url("sunset");
}
```

And the sunset jpeg is located in my assets folder.