# How to set a background image on a Rails app using CSS

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm building a rails app and trying to set a background image for the welcome page. For some reason the image won't show and I'm not sure why. I've looked at numerous questions on here but I'm still unable to resolve.

Here's my latest code -

welcome.css.scss

```
body {
  background: url('/assets/mamaknowscollage.jpg');
}
```

I've also tried (amongst numerous other variations) -

```
body {
  background-image:  url('/assets/mamaknowscollage.jpg');
}
```

Here's the html (the image tag here is for the logo)

welcome.html.erb -

```
<header>


</header>
<body>


            <image><%= link_to image_tag('MamaKnowsLogo.jpg'), root_path, id: "logo" %></image>

</body>
```

I've left the url path as is but I've also tried it without assets and it still doesn't work.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: where are your images located, i.e path example: `app/assets/images/mamaknowscollage.jpg` should work

Comment: please tell me your image location `path`

Comment: Yes, it is in the path you describe above.

Comment: could you please add your `html` code for `welcome` page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a background image in rails from css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100650/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-rails-from-css)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, I've seen that question and that solution doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If the file is in `assets/images` folder then do it like this

```
 background: image-url('mamaknowscollage.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could rename your welcome.css.scss file to welcome.scss.erb and try it out.
(SCSS will work!)

Write the path as

```
background: url('<%= asset_path 'mamaknowscollage.jpg' %>');
```

The image file should be placed in assets/images.

Source: [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#css-and-erb)

Comment: I need the file to be .scss as I'm using bootstrap.

Comment: ok! just rename your scss with .erb, i.e if welcome.css.scss - rename it to welcome.css.scss.erb, your scss will work!

Comment: But wouldn't this mean that all my style files would need to be renamed for them to work for styling purposes? For example, I have a logo on the page which is working, why would I be able to style one element but not add another?

Comment: Also check the spelling of your image if it's correct (case-sensitive) and also the extension..

Comment: I guess you have written the logo as img tag in html.erb not scss right?

Comment: Yes, I have. I have a specific photo image I want to use as the background for the welcome page. The logo I've used html.

Comment: try renaming as specified in answer, as it is the standard that is used. I have put the rails guide source link...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112982/discussion-between-ashwin-and-mike-whitehead).

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
  background-image: url(mamaknowscollage.jpg);
}
```

worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

- Firstly, rename your file to `welcome.scss.erb`.
- Then make sure to include your `welcome.scss.erb` into `application.css.erb`.

Simply add the line:

```
*= require welcome
```

- Then you should check if it works - for example, try setting the background to *blue*.
- Lastly, it should be simple to figure out the correct path to your image.

Comment: I have a logo on the welcome page which I'm able to style, why would I be able to do this but not add a background image? I've added my html above, I must be doing something wrong - it's probably dead obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: Yes, I've revised it and placed it, bordered it. All works fine.

Comment: then check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100650/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-rails-from-css

Answer (score 0):

With `scss`, you can do it as follow:

```
body {
 background:url(asset-path('mamaknowscollage.jpg')) 0px 0px;
}
```

The `mamaknowscollage.jpg` file should be placed in `assets/images`

About this problem, i think you should remove `image` tag.

```
<body>
  <%= link_to image_tag('MamaKnowsLogo.jpg'), root_path, id: "logo" %>
</body>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either - the asset-path link as you've described above does not apply the code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

First rename your css file
 `welcome.css` to `welcome.scss` and 
`application.css` to `application.scss`

in `application.scss` file add @import 'welcome'

If your images are in `app/assets/images` folder then use:

```
background: image-url("my_image.jpg");
```

If your images are in `app/assets/images/SomeFolder` folder then use:

```
background: image-url("SomeFolder/my_image.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

After much tinkering, I fixed the issue by adding a "class" to the body element on the welcome.html.erb file and applying the appropriate css code -

```
 body.background {
     background: url('mamaknowscollage.jpg');

  }
```

HTML -

```
 <body class="background">

     <div class="welcome">



         <%= image_tag('MamaKnowsLogo.jpg') %>

     </div>

 </body>
```

Thanks to all who made contributions.