# How to show a background image in ruby on rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I am running ruby 2.3.0 and rail 5.0. When trying to display an background image on a view, I use the following CSS class:

```
.header_img{
   width:100%;
   height: 400px;
   background: url("../../assets/images/home/home-header.jpg");
}
```

The image is located in the home subfolder under the image assets folder. I have tried trying to find a solution on here but have not been able to find one that works any help would be awesome.

I am using Rubymine as my IDE and nothing seems to work.

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/asset_pipeline.html says you have to use `image-url('home/home-header.jpg')`

Answer (score 4):

There is no need to provide absolute path as your image is in assests so you can directly do something like this

```
background-image: url('image.png')
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. All it does is give me this in the code background-image: url('image.png')

Comment: can you please try like this background-image: url("../../assets/images/home/home-header.jpg") by giving absolute path

Comment: check this hope it should work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100650/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-rails-from-css

Answer (score 4):

You should have a look at the asset-pipe line, see "2.3.1 CSS and ERB":

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html

> The asset pipeline automatically evaluates ERB. This means if you add
>   an erb extension to a CSS asset (for example, application.css.erb),
>   then helpers like asset_path are available in your CSS rules:

```
.class { background-image: url(<%= asset_path 'image.png' %>) }
```

Comment: My IDE says cannot find asset_path

Comment: @JohnBome Did you rename the css to css.erb? How does the css look if you run the app. (check the source) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use image_url helper without renaming the file to .erb. You just need to add extension .scss. For eg. main.css.scss and add the line like this:

`background-image: image_url('/home/image.png')`

Comment: `background-image: image_url('other-folder/image.png')` if your image is in app/assets/images/other-folder/image.png. Works in Rails 5.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar folder structure to you, and I have used a background image successfully.

Have a try of this code instead and see if it works

```
background-image:url('/assets/home/home-header.jpg');
```

Also just for extra, if you want a fixed, non repeating background image that covers the whole page add this css underneath ^that line

```
background-size:cover; 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-attachment:fixed;
height:100%;
```

Comment: I'm still not having much luck with it. I am using ruby mine as my IDE and i am getting cannot resolve file.

Answer (score 1):

I am using this approach. Its the best way to include the compiled assets.

```
.class {
background-image: asset-url('image.png');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think THIS is what he/she was looking for:

```
<div class="main-banner" style="background-image: url(' <%= polymorphic_url(:image) %>');">
```

(or whatever your active storage item was called.)