# cant add background image in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, background-image

I've been trying to add a background image to my rails app but no matter what I try I cant get it to work, this is basic stuff and I don't know what's going wrong. I had it working yesterday but my computer crashed and I hadn't saved my view file after adding the background image.

I've tried:

```
<body background="bg.png">
```

as well as:

```
background-image: url(/assets/bg.png);
```

and even:

```
body {
    background: url(bg.png);
}
```

but nothing will work, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check console. If you are getting any errors while getting file from the location that you mentioned in css?

Comment: theres no errors, i just get a white background

Answer (score 1):

To serve the image from asset-pipeline do the following:

```
body {
    background: image-url(bg.png);
}
```

To use it inline under `.erb` files:

```
<div style="background-image: url('<%= asset_path('some_image.jpg') %>') ">
```

What you are trying to do would work if the image was placed under public folder.

Similar questions: [How to set a background image in rails from css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100650/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-rails-from-css)

Comment: in which tags should i put this

Comment: You can put it under `app/assets/stylesheets/<your_stylesheet.scss>`
Make sure that you are requiring the stylesheet under `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` using `*= require <your_stylesheet>`

Comment: @JackCarter I have added one more option to use it inline

Answer (score 0):

If the image is in  public directory then

```
background-image: url('/bg.jpg')
```

If image in app/assets/images/bg.jpg

```
background-image: url('/assets/bg.jpg')
```

Also, set the below mentioned setting in developement.rb(or other environment on which you are running the code)

```
config.serve_static_assets = false  
config.assets.compress = true
config.assets.compile = false
```

Comment: in which tags should i put   background-image: url('/assets/bg.jpg')

Comment: since it is a css code thus it should be mentioned in stylesheets folder..else if you want to write inline then use the style option for adding css to html tags

Comment: i put it in the stylesheets folder in the application.css file but still nothing