# How to Modify Default Appearance using Bootstrap 4 Gem in a Rails 5 App

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Bootstrap 4 in a Rails 5 app. I'm new to web development and am trying to experiment with overriding the default visual attributes, first background color and background image.

I know there are several similar questions on StackOverflow, etc., but I have looked at them and not found a solution to my particular problem.

From what I've read, Bootstrap has a defaults file that can be edited, but because I'm using the Ruby `bootstrap` gem that contains the Bootstrap code, and that gem could be updated at any time, it would not be a good idea to modify that file directly.

Can anyone suggest how I might accomplish this? The source code is at https://github.com/keithrbennett/our_airports. If you answer, please assume I know little about CSS, Rails, etc.

Comment: You can always override the default behavior of the Bootstrap. You just need find those particular classes,set your own values,put those in a file and import that file in `application.css`

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/ create `custom.scss` and import it in `application.scss` after bootstrap imported.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I can help you with that.
So, there's no need to override default bootstrap code. This won't be feasible.
Let's take a more generalized path.

For each layout file there's a similar name file which generated in assets for stylesheets and javascripts. In your case, you're using `application.html.erb` as a layout file. So, rails generated 2 files `application.css` (which you later renamed to `.scss` to make it compatible with bootstrap gem) and `application.js`.

Hence, you might write different css files or js files for your custom designs. To use those css files you must tell the layout file to use which css files or js files.

you can do tell the layout by mentioning them in your layout's css and js files.

Here's the process you can follow:

Step 1:
create a file as style.css in app/assets/stylesheets

Step 2:
import this file in application.scss after `@import 'bootstrap'`

`@import 'style'`

Step 3:
Let's pick this file: 
app/views/airports/index.html.erb

Here you have defined

```
<th style="width:8em;"><%= sort_link "iata_code" %></th>
```

paste this code in your style.css

```
.iata-code{
  color: #999;
  width: 8em;
}
```

now modify your code to this:

```
<th class="iata-code"><%= sort_link "iata_code" %></th>
```

refresh the page and see if you can see any change.

for Background image or color
add this code in style.css

```
#for image
body { 
  background-image: image-url('pictureTitle.png'); 
}

#for color
body { 
  background: #eee; 
}
```

[you can see different ways of adding background here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100650/how-to-set-a-background-image-in-rails-from-css)

Comment: Excellent, thank you, I was able to see the change by setting the background color to a dark red. My original intent was to set the background color and/or image for the entire page though. Do you know how I would do that?

Comment: you can add a class to body tag in layouts/application.html.erb and define background: #eee; or if you want to set an image then background-url: 'url of image' see my updated answer

Comment: please accept my answer if it solved your problem :)

Comment: I've upvoted your answer, but I usually wait a day or two before accepting an answer; sometimes a way better solution comes along. Thanks for your help, your answer was very thorough and clear.

Comment: if you're going to use any image from local storage then save your image in app/assets/images.

Comment: sure, Do let me know if you still face any problem.

Comment: Sir, If it solved your problem please accept this answer. :)